# How to create a link button with a icon and button description text

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink

Hi i'm trying to create a link button with both an icon and button description text positioned next to the icon. I've added padding inside the 'A' tags so that the text will always be vertically centre, however I've tried adding the img and its now pushed the text down and increased the size of the button in the process. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

I want to make these buttons responsive for smaller devices. I can adjust the button size ok, but its the text and icon positioning that's the problem cuz I want them to always be both horizontally and vertically centred. Is there an easy way to create link buttons with an icon and text I've looked everywhere with little success. Any tutorials/advice would be really appreciated. See code below. Thanks.

The HTML:

```
<div id="reports_menu_wrapper">

    <div id="reports_menu_content">
        <a href="#" title="Product Charts"><span><img src="imgs/main_products.png" alt="" /></span>Product Charts</a>
        <a href="#" title="Speed Charts">Speed Charts</a>
        <a href="#" title="Financial Charts">Financial Charts</a>
        <a href="#" title="Usage Charts" id="usage">Usage Charts</a>
        <br class="clearFloat"/>
    </div>
```

The CSS:

```
#reports_menu_wrapper 
{
width:100%;
height:auto;
background-color:pink;
margin-top:30px;
}

#reports_menu_content
{
width:824px;
height:auto;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:#fff;
padding:10px;
border:solid 1px #ccc;
}

#reports_menu_content a 
{
display:block;
float:left;
width:198.5px;
background-color:#eee;
padding:18px 0;
outline:solid 1px #ccc;
margin-right:10px;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:75%;
color:#333;
}

#reports_menu_content a:hover 
{
background-color:#e6e6e6;
}

#reports_menu_content #usage 
{
margin-right:0;
}


#reports_menu_content a img 
{
margin-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: Use a background image for the icon, using <img> will make it harder to get the position right. Make 2 div tag above eachother, the first div contains the background-color, the second requires the background image: no repeat. Put the text in the second div and give it a padding left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a `background-image` for your `a` tag and manage the padding:

```
#reports_menu_content a 
  {
   background:orange url('yourimage.png') no-repeat left center;
   padding:0 20px 0 42px; /*42 is equal to the padding left = the image size+10px*/
  }
```

Also to center `vertical` your text you can use

```
line-height:40px;
```

Now if you want different icons for each button you can work with a Sprite.

Check this **http://jsfiddle.net/Px2zu/8/**

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me. I used the method you recommended and its worked a treat (thanks :)) the only odd thing is when I add 10px so that theres a nice gap between the icon and button, the icon will disappear when testing it on a android phone and tablet. Works fine on any apple device. If I leave out the 10px gap the icons appear on all devices. The icons are .png format. Any ideas? Thanks again.

background:url(imgs/main_products.png) no-repeat center left 10px;

Comment: Your code is invalid  center left 10px is redundant if you remove the `left` and only say `center 10px` then it can work--- try and tell me what happen

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it didn't work, its moved the icon center horizontal and 10px from the top. Although I can see the icon across all android and iphone devices

Comment: ohh so just change the order ... `10px center`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css property `vertical-align` to vertically center an element to another element. But bear in mind that this element has to be an inline element. In your case you have to apply this property with the value `middle` to your `img` elements as you want them to be vertically centered to your texts.

```
a img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I personally prefer the use of `line-height` in order to vertically center a text node and not `padding`. But it works either way.

However I would recommend you to use css classes to create the icons and the buttons.
The `.bt` class applies basic button styling, e.g. size, border, margins, etc. An `.ico` class is used to set the offset for the icon which will be applied by using another class. This class would be named after the icon and sets the `background` property. So if your icon shows an arrow, you probably would name it `.arrow`. By the way, when floating an `inline` element, it will automatically be rendered as an `block` element, so no need for the `display` property.

```
.bt {
    padding: 0 15px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font: 12px/36px Arial, "sans-serif";
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.bt.ico {
    padding-left: 41px;
}

.ico.arrow {
    background: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/entypo/58/under1-16.png") 15px center no-repeat;
}
```

I also noticed that you use an extra node to clear floats. As far as I know it is not a good practice to use extra markup for this purpose as it does not contain data. A much better practice would be to use a pseudo element. The `:after` pseudo element applied to your wrapper `#reports_menu_content` with the following css properties will clear floats:

```
.clear:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}
```

And again, use a class for it, so that it can also be applied to other wrappers.

I prepared a small fiddle which demonstrates the mentioned points: http://jsfiddle.net/w33Vk/5/